# Export Places from API Google Maps to a file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I need to export some place's data from the Google Maps API to a file (could be a text file but my final goal is to have a CSV to import to my database). 
I'm currently using their JavaScript code and some JSON method to display the content of my results.

**My goal**:
Create a variable `foundPlaces` which contains all the places according to the type of place I'm looking for. Then put all this data out the an downloaded file.

I'm currently facing a problem here since when I open the file, I can only see the first array `["name","type","geo"];` nothing more (no data from the places). That's weird because I can display them on the `console.log`
More info: I'm using `Blob` to put all my content and export this blob into a file.

**Here's my code**

```
var foundPlaces = ["name","type","geo"];

    function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      console.log("Creating File");   
      test = results[0].name;

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker(results[i]);    
          foundPlaces.push(results[i].name);      
        }   
      }
    }

  console.log(foundPlaces);
  download(foundPlaces, 'places.txt', 'text/plain');
```

It might be the type of the content, I clearly don't know where I'm wrong. I will be thankful for your help.

I'm aware that I'm asking to play with the client side.

Comment: Can you supply an example of the data object that you have?

Comment: Hi @Makore thank you for your help. I fixed my problem using the same method as you. Adding an "onclick button" in the HTML code. ' <button onclick="download(foundPlaces, 'places.csv', 'text/plain')">Recuperer CSV</button> '. It's working this way. However I wanted to make it download automatically at the end of the script : that's why I called the function inside the script. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the a to the body, encode the data and add charset.

**Note:** I hardcoded the mime type, but fill free to pass it as an argument to the function.

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  a.setAttribute('download', filename);
  a.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

```html
<!-- Example -->
<button onclick="download('test.txt', 'I love text')">Click to download</button>
```

Comment: Your code woks fine, thank you. What should I do now, if I want to make it download automatically ?

Comment: @Squicker I'm glad I could help. You can add the function download as a callback to the ajax call for example. The flow should be in this fashion:
1. Make a call to the Google API
2. Format the data from the ajax request 
3. Send the formatted data to the download function